# How can I detect changes in UITextField when I change textfield.text property?

Tags: ios

I'm managing user actions in UITextField with `func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool` and it works perfectly but if I set textField.text = "String" 
This is not being called, I also tried with IBActions like valueChanged and DidEndEditing with no success

Any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: Did you set the delegate for textField?

Answer (score 0):

The delegate methods are not called when you change the text property programmatically.

But when you change the property in code you **know** that and when the value changed.

For example write a common function

```
func updateTextField(with string: String) {
    textField.text = string
    doSomethingAfterTextChanged()
}
```

Or use a property observer which is called when the value of `textFieldValue` changed

```
var textFieldValue : String {
    didSet {
        textField.text = textFieldValue
        doSomethingAfterTextChanged()
    }
}
```

Comment: It will help me although it is not exactly the solution I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. Add this code in your viewDidLoad

```
yourTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged);
```

Add this function in your viewController

```
 @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField)
 {
        // you are done check your value do something
 }
```